# Serious application error. Model object getting NSFetchedResultsController message

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a very odd error with `Core Data`. I have a `Recipe` class that has a many to many relationship to an `Ingredient` class.

When I try to add an `Ingredient` to the `Recipe` on a `RecipeViewController`, everything works fine until I save the context. Thats when things go horribly wrong.

I get an error on my `RecipesTableViewController` (which has a `NSFetchedResultsController` and implements `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`). The

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

method gets called and then I get an exception:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   -[KCGIngredient sectionOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf83d50 with userInfo (null)

I have no idea what this `sectionOffset` message is and couldn't find it in the documentation. This happens after `NSFetchResultsController` gets the `_postprocessInsertedObjects:` message.

I'm assuming this `sectionOffset` message was intended to an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I have no idea how it ended up being sent to a model object.

**EDIT:**

Actually, I checked it out and apparently `sectionOffset` is not a method of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

This test fails miserably:

```
XCTAssertTrue([NSFetchedResultsController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(sectionOffset)]);
```

What on Earth is going on?  I already tried everything,s o if you can shed some light, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This kind of error is often an indication that an object has been deallocated and different class of object created (coincidentally) in its place.  One way to debug this is to "turn on zombies".  If you search on this phrase you will find various questions and answers which might help you to pin down the problem.

Comment: Is `sectionOffset` a method on `KCGIngredient`?

Comment: @TomHarrington Absolutely not.  That's why I'm getting the unrecognized selector exception. I implemented a stub for ```sectionOffset```just to see what happens, but I just get sent another method that ```KCGIngredient```doesn't understand either.

Comment: @pbasdf Zombies didn't help either. I just get the error right after ```NSFetchResultsController``` gets the ```_postprocessInsertedObjects:```

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up the FRC, and its delegate methods?  Thanks.